# Proving Linear Independence Given Odd Absolute Values

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

With three vectors $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3$, the magnitude of a$,b,c,a-b,b-c$, and $c-a$ are all odd integers (not necessarily distinct).

How could you prove the three vectors are linearly independent?
You can notice any two are pair wise independent through odd/even considerations, but I'm stuck with all $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that one of them is generatable by a
linear combination of the other two. Without loss of generality, say
$a = l_1 b + l_2 c$
for some $l_1,l_2 \in \mathbb{R}.$ We see that $a$ is of odd magnitude, so
$l_1 b + l_2 c$ should be of odd magnitude. We also know that
$a - c = l_1 b + (l_2 - 1) c$ is of odd magnitude. Can it be that both
$l_1 b + l_2 c$ and $l_1 b + (l_2 - 1) c$ can be of odd magnitude? I would ask
that you work out the algebra to check if one of these leads to a contradiction
related to $b$ or $c$.